# If we assign a new value to a variable, what happens to the old value ? (in C)

Tags: c, variables, reference

From the book : "Programming in C (4th Edition)" by Stephen G Kochan

```
// Basic conversions in C

#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    float  f1 = 123.125, f2;
    int    i1, i2 = -150;
    char   c = 'a';

    i1 = f1;                 // floating to integer conversion
    printf("%f assigned to an int produces %i\n", f1, i1);

    f1 = i2;                 // integer to floating conversion
    printf("%i assigned to a float produces %f\n", i2, f1);

    f1 = i2 / 100;           // integer divided by integer
    printf("%i divided by 100 produces %f\n", i2, f1);

    f2 = i2 / 100.0;           // integer divided by a float
    printf("%i divided by 100.0 produces %f\n", i2, f2);

    f2 = (float) i2 / 100;     // type cast operator
    printf("(float) %i divided by 100 produces %f\n", i2, f2);
    return 0;
}
```

I am new to programming and I was trying to learn how to program in C from the above mentioned book. And I came across this snippet of code for converting integers to floats and vice versa. I am a bit confused as to what actually happens.

Here is what I understand so far :
The first few lines (`float f1 = 123.135, f2;` and the next two lines) declare the variables.

Then the line `i1 = f1;` assigns the value of `123.125` to the variable named `i1` but since `i1` is an integer, its truncated to `123`.

Now, here is my question, in the next line `f1 = i2;` the value `-150` is assigned to the variable named `f1` but since its a `float`, the value is stored as a float i.e. `-150.000000` but what happened to `123.125` ?

Does that value still exist somewhere in the computers memory ? if so how can I access it ? like before when that value was assigned to `f1`, I could just refer to it as `f1` but now that it is no longer assigned to any variable, can I refer to it in some way ?

Like a more generalized version would be, if we assign a new value to a variable, what happens to the old value ?

I have taken a gander at [In python when we assign a new value to a variable what happens to the old one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61913056/in-python-when-we-assign-a-new-value-to-a-variable-what-happens-to-the-old-one)
but does the same happen in C ?

Comment: The memory allocated to a variable is overwritten by a new value. What is unclear?

Comment: Think of a C variable as about a name temporarily given to a memory address*. When you assign to a variable, you overwrite things at that address, the old value is gone. (*Technically, this may not always be the case.)

Comment: A variable can only hold one value, so if you assign a new value to a variable the old value is gone.

Comment: And for the linked Python question: No, that is not relevant for C. It's about a much more complicated type of code and system. C doesn't have the functionality described there.

Comment: Physically, the memory chip holds some electrons (a 1-bit), or doesn't hold them (a 0-bit), in certain positions. When you store a new value, the electrons are rearranged to hold the new bits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C, the variable is a name that is used to make a piece of memory easier to use.  When you assign a value to the variable, the value is stored into a piece of memory that corresponds to the variable name.

This means that upon storing a new value into the variable the old value is overwritten as the variable still references the same piece of memory.  Generally, the first value isn't retained in any way that can later be accessed.

Now there are "exotic" ways of doing things that might not make this statement 100% true.  There are Copy-on-Write systems (some of which are implemented in C) that do retain old values (in the general sense) when new values are written.  However, these kinds of systems are not even present in the majority of C programs, and if you were using one, you'd know it.

Comment: *However, these kinds of systems are not even present in the majority of C programs, and if you were using one, you'd know it*... actually most people use such systems without knowing :) many current desktops and smartphones use virtual memory that relies on this mechanism to speed up program launch, eps. the `fork` system call. But this occurs at the OS level, beyond the reach of the running C program.

Answer (score 0):

> Does that value still exist somewhere in the computers memory ?

The general answer is: No, once you assign a new value to a variable the old value is gone and consequently you can't access it.

That said...

Depending on your compiler, initializers (like yours 123.125) may be part of the program memory and therefore the value may still be somewhere in memory. However, that doesn't really matter cause you can't know where and therefore can't access it. So for any practical use, it's gone...

Answer (score 0):

whenever you make a variable and assign it a value it gets stored in the memory but when we change the variable's value we are basically replacing it with new value.so the old value gets removed from the memory

Answer (score 0):

The variable is like a placeholder for a value. If you assign a new value to a variable it means your overwriting the old value with the new one and the old value is gone forever.